# What is the English word that can represent the thing that a role is applied on?

Tags: single-word-requests

- Your role in the **school** is a teacher.
- His role in the **team** is a developer.
- Her role in the **family** is a mother.

human + **something** (e.g school, team, and family) + role

What we can call the thing that the role is applied on? Is there an English term that can represents the "**something**" in the equation?

Comment: There are no umbrella terms that will capture all of these. The loosest I can think of is "organization" — families, schools and teams are all types of organization — but if you use that term you will probably make people think of something else entirely.

Comment: I don't understand "the thing that the role is applied on." *Role: teacher*. What else are you referring to?

Comment: @JasonBassford, if the role is teacher, what is the term that we can use to describe the school in this relation (the role subject, the context, or ...)?

Comment: I find the question strange. A school is a building or, perhaps,  a teaching environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term I would use would be ***context***.  Each example you gave specified a role and the context for that role.  From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[context](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/context)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. The circumstances that form the setting for an event, statement, or idea, and in terms of which it can be fully understood.
>
>    *‘the proposals need to be considered in the context of new European directives’*

Comment: Thanks @Roger, can I also use "the role subject"?!

Comment: @MohamedShehata - I suppose you could, but _subject_ carries the connotation of being smaller or contained within.  [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subject) defines it as _A person or thing that is being discussed, described, or dealt with._  The subject of a _teachers role_ might be something like math or art while the subject of a _mother's role_ is to care for and provide for her family.  Consider this: A woman might have children and the president of a corporation.  In the context of her family, she is the mother; in the context of her company, she is the president.

Comment: For that same woman, the subject of her role as mother is making lunches, checking homework, etc.  In her role as president, the subject of her efforts is making sure the company behaves in an ethical, considerate way while still making a profit.